# How do I present a custom view only along the right?

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboard

I want to present my view as a column on the right side of the screen. This app will be iPad only. [image: Here ya go]

Comment: Please post your work-in-progress implementation.

Comment: I have none, just an image of what I want it to look like.

Comment: @JonathanAllenGrant Then you should try it for yourself before seeking help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be to create a view controller that way; drag out a new view controller from the asset library into your storyboard, set the background color to black and bring the opacity to 50%. Then drag out a UIView and set its constraints so that it is pinned to the right side. You need to present it modally. This is usually done by control-dragging from some button or other control in the original view controller to the new view controller and selecting "present modally".

To recreate the effect like in the picture you posted, you don't want the presenting view controller to disappear in the background. To make sure the presenting view controller stays around, you can use a custom presentation controller. To do this, add this to your new view controller (the one that displays the view on the right side):

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Custom
    transitioningDelegate = self
}
```

Now create a PresentationController, which is just a subclass of `UIPresentationController`. The only method you need to implement in this PresentationController is `shouldRemovePresentersView()`:

```
override func shouldRemovePresentersView() -> Bool {
    return false
}
```

Add an extension to the presented (or second) view controller (the one that contains `modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Custom` and `transitioningDelegate = self`) or conform to the UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate protocol some other way:

```
extension YourViewController: UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {

    // Need this presentation controller so that view controller in background
    // isn't deallocated and therefore appears through the background.
    func presentationControllerForPresentedViewController(presented: UIViewController, presentingViewController presenting: UIViewController!, sourceViewController source: UIViewController) -> UIPresentationController? {
        return YourPresentationControllersName(presentedViewController: presented, presentingViewController: presenting)
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm getting an error on this line: `transitioningDelegate = self`
"Cannot assign a value of type 'EventColumnViewController' to a value of type 'UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate?"

Comment: @JonathanAllenGrant You need to conform to the `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate` protocol by either creating an extension (like in the bottom of my answer) or just adding that delegate protocol after the superclass in your class declaration

Comment: I'm a bit confused. By "presenting (or first) view controller" do you mean my new PresentationController, my new ViewController for the view on the right, or the original view controller behind the column on the right?

Comment: @JonathanAllenGrant I updated my answer. I wrote the presenting view controller, but I meant the present**ed** view controller. It should work now.

Comment: It works! You are my hero today <3

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a fully-customizable CocoaControl:

[REFrostedViewController](https://github.com/romaonthego/REFrostedViewController)

Create controllers programatically:

```
// Create content and menu controllers
//
DEMONavigationController *navigationController = [[DEMONavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[DEMOHomeViewController alloc] init]];
DEMOMenuViewController *menuController = [[DEMOMenuViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];

// Create frosted view controller
//
REFrostedViewController *frostedViewController = [[REFrostedViewController alloc] initWithContentViewController:navigationController menuViewController:menuController];
frostedViewController.direction = REFrostedViewControllerDirectionLeft;

// Make it a root controller
//
self.window.rootViewController = frostedViewController;
```

Or just subclass your storyboard controllers.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Container view. Set the width of the container view proportional to that of the main view.

[image]

Now you can design the view controller(blue colored in above image) as you want and it will be displayed as you wanted.

[image: Like this you can add anything you want to be displayed]

Then just run it in an iPad simulator. You will get you view in the right side of the screen.

[image]

Hope this helps you.

Comment: How do I toggle the visibility of the container?

Comment: Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: Yeah, sorry about the delay. I want to be able to press a button and reveal the container view, as well as swipe the container view away from the screen.