# error using cocoapods "use_frameworks!" SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, residemenu

I had a clean swift project, using some cocoapods : Parse, AFNetworking and RESideMenu.
I need to use [STZPopupView](http://cocoapods.org/pods/STZPopupView) pod, so I updated cocoapods with the last version:

```
gem install cocoapods
```

Then I relaunched it for my project:

```
pod install
```

Because of this error :

```
[!] Pods written in Swift can only be integrated as frameworks; this feature is still in beta. Add `use_frameworks!` to your Podfile or target to opt into using it.
```

I updated my podfile adding "use_frameworks!"

My podfile is now:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

target 'isam' do
pod 'RESideMenu', '~> 4.0.7'
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.5'
pod 'Parse', '~> 1.6'
pod 'STZPopupView', '~> 1.0'
end

target 'isamTests' do

end
```

Since, I have 2 errors when I build :

- "RESideMenu.h" file not found
- Failed to import bridging header "..../isam/Swift-Bridging-Header.h"

I didn't changed anything else in my project.

My Swift-Bridging-Header.h doesn't change :

```
#ifndef isam_Swift_Bridging_Header_h
#define isam_Swift_Bridging_Header_h

#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import <RESideMenu.h>

#endif
```

In my build settings, I have :

[image: builds settings]

I think it's because of "use_frameworks!" in my podfile, but I don't know how to do to use all of my pods to build my app correctly.

EDIT :

The exact errors are :

```
/path_of_my_project/Swift-Bridging-Header.h:12:9: error: 'RESideMenu.h' file not found
#import <RESideMenu.h>
        ^
<unknown>:0: error: failed to import bridging header '/path_of_my_project/Swift-Bridging-Header.h'
```

Comment: Remove these statements from the bridging header file:                      #ifndef isam_Swift_Bridging_Header_h & #define isam_Swift_Bridging_Header_h and endif. It should work.

Comment: @dilip.ajm The #ifndef simply keeps it from getting imported multiple times as far as I can tell

Comment: @SantaClaus I tried with and without quotes, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm actually on the same problem. You could try this: http://www.innerexception.com/2015/05/cocoapods-useframeworks-means-bridging.html

When using use_frameworks! in CocoaPods all of your pods will be used as frameworks, not only the swift pods. So you don't need an bridging header for this. Just import your pods into all swift files you need. 
In your example you have to write:
import RESideMenu

Comment: This fixed it for me. However I also I got a "duplication of interface declaration" that I fixed by changing my Objective-C files that were importing headers from frameworks into using global includes instead of local: `#import "Framework.h"` to `#import <Framework/Framework.h>`.

Answer (score 2):

Try removing isam/ from the Objective-C Bridging Header and have only Swift-Bridging-Header.h

Coming from personal experience, CocoaPods still have some issues when combining swift and Objective C frameworks. You can use Alamofire which is almost equivalent of AFNetworking for swift.

Hope this helps.

Edit : 
Also why use Objectice-C Parse in swift when you can directly use swift libraries.

Comment: Remove isam/ doesn't work. Indeed, I need the pod STZPopupView because I would like to custom the uialertcontroller : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254931/add-an-animation-image-per-image-inside-a-uialertcontroller-swift

Comment: ok I was able to successfully build the project using your specification.
only thing that I needed to change was to modify this 
    #import <RESideMenu/RESideMenu.h>

Also try removing target 'isam' do from your pod file and make sure to run all pod terminal commands inside the project directory

Comment: when you said "remove the target isam", you ask me to remove completely the line "target 'isam' do"/"end" in my podfile?

Comment: target 'isam' do should be removed from the pod File, but asked before to remove it from Header file location in Build Settings. I dont have that and  never had to include project directory in Build Setting.

I'd recommend just add Header.h in there are create a new hear file with the name Header to make things simplified (Naming this way is not best practice but can help you narrowing down and find the issue)

Comment: what is your cocoa pods version?

Comment: I follow your instructions it doesn't work too :( I copy the exact errors in my question.

Comment: this stzpopupview is nothing more than you could achieve with a normal modally presented view controller

Comment: Swift stuff is still by far more error prone than Obj-C libs.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I changed all my imports from `#import "RESideMenu.h"` to `#import <RESideMenu/RESideMenu.h>` for example.